# How to transfer a Motion (5) project between Macs?

Tags: data-transfer

I need to be able to work on a motion project on-the-go on a MacBook Pro, but it really seems to be lagging performance wise, so I want to transfer the project to a iMac while at home, and to transfer it back onto the MacBook when I go out again. So how do I transfer the active project along with all required data easily between two computers?

Edit:
Never mind, apparently when you save you can save as a folder, copying all the media into that folder. I'll just leave this up for others who have the same question.

Comment: You should answer your own question so "others who have the same question" would notice this has an answer and it is accepted :-)

Answer (score 2):

When you save you can save as a folder ("Copy Media"), and it will copy all the media into a folder in the folder of the project, allowing it to be moved around.

Answer (score 2):

If the size of the associated media files make copying prohibitive, booting your laptop in target disk mode (hold down 'T' key while booting) is a great solution that has worked for me many times.

Answer (score 0):

You can always sync your files with dropbox.

Comment: That probably isn't going to work, because dropbox doesn't actually sync files per se, it only allows easy access to them on different computers via the "cloud".

Comment: From your question, you said that you wanted to be able to access your files when you're at home, so you should be able to use dropbox to synchronize your files in between when you're not using each computers.

Comment: Yes, but you see, a motion project isn't by itself the whole package. It requires all the video/effects/audio that is featured in the project, and need to be able to locate them.

Comment: Would you like to list out the directories of the project files that you need so that we can help you?